# UUID Is not JSON Serializable (dumpdata)

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, uuid

I'm having an issue with the command `dumpdata`. I'm using [`django-uuidfield`](https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield) as primary key for a few of my models, however; whenever I try to run `dumpdata`, I run into the error

`TypeError: UUID('...') is not JSON serializable`.

I found that inside of Django's [`DjangoJSONEncoder`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py#L87) class that it doesn't check for the `UUID` object and will go to the `default()` of the parent class which throws the exception.

When I added a check, it seemed to work properly without any errors or warnings.

I'm not sure if that's a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

**Note:**

I didn't change any code inside `django-uuidfield`.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The `dumpdata` works for another model where the `uuidfield` is not set to `auto`. The one that doesn't work has the `uudfield` set to `auto`.

Comment: It's not you. It's a bug: https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield/issues/47

Comment: I looked at that but what I noticed is that it's working for one of my models. The difference between the two is that the one that doesn't work is `auto` while the the one that works is not `auto`.

Comment: I see. I haven't investigated why using auto would fail, but its not terribly difficult to just leave `auto` off and set the value with a `save()` override.

Answer (score 0):

In my models.py:

```
import uuid
```

In my model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

and to solve this problem, I use this function write in MyUser:

```
def user_id(self):
    return self.id.__str__()
```

As the TypeError try you that type `UUID` is not JSON serializable,

so you should use `string` instead.

Hope it will help you.